# AJAX load more on scroll to bottom in <div>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I wanna load data from mysql using AJAX and PHP function.
Example:

```css
#ajaxload {
border: 1px solid #000;
max-height: 400px;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<?php
//data from mysql...
?>
<div id="ajaxload">
<ul>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>data...</li>
<li>Loading next data...</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

But I didn't find here (on stackoverflow) the specific example...Everything is just with full page scrolling, but I want only scrolling in `<div>` for loading more data. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Get the [scrollHeight](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrollheight.asp)  property from the underlying DOM element:

```
$("#ajaxload").scrollTop($("#ajaxload").get(0).scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS approach, [example](https://codepen.io/mazdok/pen/zYqYYex?editors=1010).

```
<div id="ajaxload">
  <ul>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>data...</li>
    <li>Loading next data...</li>
  </ul>
</div>

const el = document.querySelector('#ajaxload');

el.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
    const element = event.target;
  
    if (element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight) {
        console.log('make now your API call...');
    }
});
```